# Is there an easier way to add multiple Mail Merge fields into separate table cells?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, mail-merge

I have to create a relatively large Microsoft Word template file that will contains a couple of hundred Mail Merge fields. Some of these are duplicate fields but that isn't too much of an issue.

I have an Access database that contains all the available merge fields, I have added this as the Recipient List and the "Insert Merge Field" list (in the "Mailings" tab) successfully shows the full list.

Each field has to go into a separate table cell.

The method I am currently using is as follows:

1. Select the target cell
2. Click the "Insert Merge Field" button (which shows a modal form with the list)
3. Select the item I want and insert it (which can take a few seconds to scroll and find the item I want)
4. Close the modal box (because I cannot select another cell with it still open)
5. Repeat

This is to say the least very time consuming. It would be perfect if I didn't have to close the "Insert Merge Field" each time and I could just select the new cell and insert the new value, but I cannot.

Is there some other method I could use to help speed up this process? Is there a way I can select the new cell without closing the "Insert Merge Field" box?

Comment: I guess you have already done the leg work, but to deal with this kind of situation I think you probably have to use a combination of techniques, depending on a number of factors. For example, if you know the field names (even if there are a lot) then you could type the names in the cells and use a VBA macro to convert them to MERGEFIELD fields. Or you could insert all the field names in some helpful sequence in a separate document (again, a bit of VBA would be helpful there) and copy/paste as required. A non-modal dialog built in VBA may also be possible.

Comment: @bibadia: An interesting idea. Sounds like it would work in my case. Though I have done only a little VBA in the past and it was quite some time ago, so I would have to factor in the time it would take to do. I may give it a go though if I get an hour or two spare at some point. Thanks for the suggestion! I especially like the though of being able to produce my own dialog for it... I could add a sort too then!